# Their or They're?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Normally, I'm not stumped with this but I have a phrase that I can't figure out which would be the correct one to use..

> ".. for all their worth."

OR

> ".. for all they're worth."

Personally, I think both are correct but I am leaning more towards `they're` although `their` seems to be also plausible. I wonder if anyone can provide an insight into what might be the correct/better one to use.

### Update:

So in this case, the context is somewhere along the lines of suing someone or taking legal action for all _____ worth.

Comment: Both could be correct depending on the rest of the sentence. Please complete the sentence so we can say which is right

Comment: @gotube I could not have expressed it better. Well done.

Comment: If you mean 'with great energy', it's _for all they're (they are) worth_ - see [this definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/for%20all%20someone%20is%20worth#:~:text=%3A%20as%20much%20as%20possible%20or,for%20all%20he%20was%20worth.)

Comment: @gotube Updated the question to include the context.

Comment: There is an [English.se] answer about this https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/190259/for-all-its-worth-or-for-all-its-worth/190269#190269

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct form is "for all they're worth".  [This idiom](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/for%20all%20someone%20is%20worth#:%7E:text=%3A%20as%20much%20as%20possible%20or,for%20all%20he%20was%20worth.) is "for all (something, someone) is worth", with "is" changed to "are" for the plural.

But this is a fairly common native-speaker error too, as discussed on our sister site https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/190259/for-all-its-worth-or-for-all-its-worth/190269

Answer (score 1):

Two correct phrases with different meanings.

Someone’s “worth” can mean the worthiness of a person, or the value of their possessions.

“For all their worth” - the combined value of their possessions.

“For all they’re worth” - their combined worthiness.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "for all they are worth", use "they're".

If you mean "for all the worth they have", use "their".

The first is more common, because we usually say things, or even people, are worth something. However, we do sometimes speak of a person's worth, especially someone's *net worth*.